# Bad byte count while using hexdump

Tags: files, freebsd, binary, hexdump

I am trying to display a binary file with records consisting of:

```
8 bytes unsigned int
4 bytes unsigned int
4 bytes unsigned int
4 bytes unsigned int
4 bytes unsigned int
```

I try to display it using `hexdump` as follows:

```
hexdump -v -e '1/8 "%015d " 4/4 " %6d" "\n"' binfile
```

But I get:

```
hexdump: d: bad byte count
```

I am using FreeBSD 12 -if relevant-

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [man page](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=hexdump&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD%2012.0-RELEASE&arch=default&format=html),

> ```
>      %d, %i, %o, %u, %X, %x  Four byte default, one, two and four byte
>                              counts supported.
> ```

And there  doesn't appear to be any integer type where eight byte is supported (you'd also need `%u`, not `%d` for *unsigned* ints).

You could use `perl` instead here:

```
perl -ne 'BEGIN{$/ = \24} # 24 byte input records
          printf "%015u %6u %6u %6u %6u\n", unpack "QL4"' < binfile
```

(`QL4` being 1 unsigned quad (64bit) followed by 4 unsigned longs (32bit))

Comment: It works and it is simple and straightforward.

Comment: Other data types (floats&doubles) can be found here: https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pack